# Pulling Facebook profile pic with parse using Swift

Tags: facebook, swift, parse-platform, profile

I'm trying to pull the username and profile picture for my apps profile page. I'm using Parse and the Facebook SDK.

I have a UILabel and a UIView connected as outlets.

When I try to set the profileImageView, it gives me the error **"Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'setImageWithURL'"** Is this an upgrade with Swift?

Here is my code...

```
func setProfilePicture() {
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if let dict = result as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            let name: String = dict["name"] as! String
            let facebookID: String = dict["id"] as! String

            let pictureUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(facebookID)/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1"

            self.profileImageView.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: pictureUrl)!)
            self.nameLabel.text = name
            PFUser.currentUser()!.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
            PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackground()
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/\(facebookID)/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1") {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
        self.profileImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        self.profileImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a function, `fbProfilePicURL`, that takes a Facebook ID and returns the profile picture URL as an `NSURL`, then change

```
self.profileImageView.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: pictureUrl)!)
```

to

```
self.profileImageView.setImageWithURL(NSURL.fbProfilePicURL(facebookID))
```

Not 100% sure on this, but let me know if it works.

Comment: I should have added that I'm using cocoapods in my program. I was missing the AFNetworking, so I installed it and added "import AFNetworking". That let me access the 'setImageWithURL' and now everything works!